# How to calculate axis ticks at a uniform distribution?

Tags: equals, distribution, partitioning, bucket

Given a data range by its minimum and maximum value, how can one calculate the distribution of buckets on a an axis?
**The requirements are:**
- The axis ticks shall be evenly distributed (equal size).
- Further, all ticks shall appear as numbers like `10, 20, 30, ...` or `-0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, ...`
- The calculation shall accept a parameter that defines the number of buckets wanted.

The following example calculates a maximum of 10 buckets or less.

```
num buckets = 10
range length = 500
500 / 10 = 50
log_10(50) = 1,69
round up(1,69) = 2
10^2 = 100 bucket size
500 / 100 = 5 buckets
```

Result: There are 5 buckets each at a size of 100.
The steps only produce buckets that are based on `10^x` which are `0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000 ...`

How can one calculate the buckets size for exactly 42 buckets?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but i think this code can help you (Adapted from JavaScript YUI [YAHOO.util.DragDrop.js](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/DragDrop.js.html))

```
var initPosition = 0;
var rangeLength  = 500;
var maxPosition  = (initPosition + rangeLength);
getTicks: function(bucketSize) {
    var axisTicks = [];

    var tickMap = {};
    for (i = initPosition; i <= maxPosition; i = i + bucketSize) {
        if (!tickMap[i]) {
            axisTicks[axisTicks.length] = i;

            tickMap[i] = true;
        }
    }

    return axisTicks;
}
```

The drawback is because, sometimes, the axis ticks will not be evenly distributed ((initPosition + rangeLength) / bucketSize) does not return a plain integer